# React i18next - Custom formatter doesn't work

Tags: internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I'm using ICU format and would like to add a custom formatter that will lowercase a string.

To do so I've used this configuration

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import enTranslation from "./locales/en/translation.json"
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import ICU from 'i18next-icu';

i18n
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(ICU)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        debug: true,
        initImmediate: false,
        resources: {
            en: enTranslation
        },
        lng: "en", // if you're using a language detector, do not define the lng option
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
        }
    });

i18n.services.formatter?.add("lowercase", (value, lng, options) => {
    return value.toLowerCase();
});

export default i18n;
```

I load this configration into my `index.tsx`

```
import './i18n';
```

translation.json

```
{
  "translation": {
    "custom-format": "Example {value, lowercase}."
  }
}
```

If I try and use this message it just prints out the options. E.g.

```
// Prints as "Example {value, lowercase}."
<Trans i18nKey="custom-format" values={{value: "MiXtUrE"}}/>
```

I've checked if the formatter exists in the i18next object and it does. It is however missing its name.

[image]

Why won't it use the custom formatter?

Comment: custom formatter us for the i18next format only, not for ICU